# Synchronization failure between Redux and render()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
class CategoryFeed extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      params,
      getForum,
    } = this.props;
    getForum(params.fid);
  }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {
      currentForum,
    }
    alert(currentForum._id); // WORKS WELL
}
...
render() {
    const {
      currentForum,
    } = this.props;

alert(currentForum._id); // ERROR!
...
export default connect(
  (state) => { return {
    currentForum: state.app.currentForum,
...
(dispatch) => { return {
getForum: (forum, fid) => { 
      dispatch(getForum(forum, fid));   
    },
  }; }
)(CategoryFeed);
```

As you see in the end of the code, I have "currentForum" that is registered in store.

In "componentDidMount()", I call "getForum(params.fid)" which updates "currentForum" internally.

Then, I try to check if "currentForum" is updated by calling "alert(currentForum._id);" in the render() function.

However, it results in error that currentForum is not defined. However, "alert(currentForum._id);" in "componentDidUpdate(prevProps)" works fine. It does alert the proper value.

How can I make currentForum set before calling render() to work in render() function in this kind of structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent `render()` from being called but you can do a safety check with `currentForum`:

```
render() {
  const { currentForum } = this.props;
  if (!currentForum) {

    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {currentForum}
    </div>
  );
}
```